# filling combo box

Tags: c#, mysql

how to populate a combobox using 3tier architecture?i have used this code;

```
private void BindDepName()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;password=sa;database=employeedetails");
        con.Open();
        string MySql = "SELECT * FROM tbldept";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySql, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DepName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DepName.ValueMember = "Dept_id";
        DepName.DisplayMember = "Dept_name";
        string i = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        DepName.Text = "select dept";
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in a 3tier world you will have one class in the `BusinessLogic` class library which returns some kind of enumerable (IEnumerable, List, Collection, array...) of `Entities` to the user interface; as good practice the UI should not work directly with DataTable and DataSet.

the actual type of objects you are returning to fill the UI controls (combo box in your case) depends on your design and preferences, if you use Entity Framework you can have entities defined and modeled in the EF designer/model.

the lower part of the architecture is the `Dala Access Layer`, imagine it as a class library that is **the only one** allowed and capable to estabilish the connection to the database, so the mySql connection management and actual query execution should be isolated and not exposed upwards from the DAL.

UI calls BL which calls DAL.

DAL connects to the database, queries and returns entities to BL.

BL returns entities (kind of collection) to the UI for binding.

to give it a try and keep it simple, only for starting, you can skip the entity modeling and return datatable so you can test the logic. :)

Comment: how to code for combo box in presentation layer,bl,dal classes

Comment: Please google for it! For example I found this: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/IntroductionTo3TierArchitecture.aspx

Comment: can displaymember and value member be used in DAL class?

Comment: DisplayMember and ValueMember have to be set in the UI only, only UI knows what these members are and mean, DAL and BL know nothing about the UI controls you use to show the data.

Comment: Nice answer on strange question :)..No, really, @fida, you are asking about practical thing in the certain architectural solution. Sure you can populate your combobox with any datasource(its an object), no matter HOW you got that datasource. So your real problem is to populate datasource in 3-tier. The code you wrote-is not 3 tier. You connect to DB right from codebehind and not through some proxy class/classes(usually services that work with DB, and ONLY them do have access to it..).